# How to pass props or state from parent to child react in this format

Tags: reactjs

I already have a foreknowledge of passing props or state from parent to child like this

```
 class Parent extends React.Component{
    state = {name: "parent-state"}
    update = () => {
      this.setState(state => state.name="example-state"})
    }
    render(){
    return (
    <ChildComponent {...this.state, update: this.update} />
    )

    }
```

Now my question is how to achieve this same feat in this format

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
    state = {name: "parent-state"}
    update = () => {
      this.setState(state => state.name="example-state"})
    }
    render(){
    return (
    {this.props.children}
    )

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
render() {
   return React.cloneElement(this.props.children[0], {...this.state});
}
```